# GWT - Select all on text box after click

Tags: java, javascript, dom, gwt, java-native-interface

In my GWT project I have an `Element desc` which is represented with a `TextArea`. I need to select all the text when the user clicks on it. The JNI function `selectAll()` is correctly executed when the user clicks on the element. However, it does not select the text. Please help!

```
final Element desc = StoryView.getInstance().getDescription();
DOM.sinkEvents((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, Event.ONCLICK);
DOM.setEventListener((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, new EventListener(){        
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event e) {
            switch (DOM.eventGetType(e)) {
                case Event.ONCLICK:
                  selectAll();
                  break;
            }               
        }
    });
}

private native void selectAll() /*-{
    var desc = @com.gw.myproj.client.story.StoryView::DESC; 
    $wnd.$("." + desc).focus();
    $wnd.$("." + desc).select();
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try with JavaScript's [setSelectionRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method in JSNI.

```
private native void selectAll(Element element) /*-{
    element.setSelectionRange(0, element.value.length);
}-*/;

final Element desc = Document.get().createTextInputElement();
DOM.sinkEvents((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, Event.ONCLICK);
DOM.setEventListener((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event e) {
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(e)) {
            case Event.ONCLICK:
                selectAll(desc);
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Note: No need to call `focus` because when you click on it it will be focused automatically.